# How to do jQuery autocomplete that passes a id and not a name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I was looking for jQuery UI Autocomplete because I needed on a `<input />` but the problem is that I need to pass the id of the name completed. Let me explain:

I have an array of names:

```
$names = array(
    array('name' => 'John', id => '1'),
    array('name' => 'Sarah', id => '2'),
    array('name' => 'Josh', id => '3)
);
```

And then, with AJAX, the input will be autocompleted with one name of the array but then, when I submit, I need the id and not the name. How can I manage?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) control can accept the list of search results as a set of Display/Value objects.

From memory, you create a Json object in the following format...

```
[
    {label:"Display Name for result 1", value:1},
    {label:"Display Name for result 2", value:2},
    {label:"Display Name for result 3", value:3}
]
```

The label property contains the text to display and the value proberty contains the id. These values can be inspected when a search result is selected by the user. The control has a `select` event that you can listen for.

Answer (score 8):

Your need to save the id into a hidden field.

You can achieve that on the "select" event. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select

This example shows the select event http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

So the idea is to do something like this:

```
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
        }
```